# Does the Apostle Paul imply that the unbelief of the Jews was the cause for the Gentiles to obtain mercy in Romans 11?

Tags: romans

NASB

Romans 11

> [12]Now if their transgression is riches for the world and their failure is riches for the Gentiles, how much more will their fulfillment be!

Romans 11

> [17]But if some of the branches were broken off, and you, being a wild olive, were grafted in among them and became partaker with them of the rich root of the olive tree,

Romans 11

> [30]For just as you once were disobedient to God, but now have been shown mercy because of their disobedience,

In the above texts it would seem the Apostle is saying that the failure of the Jewish nation was the cause for the Gentiles to obtain mercy.
How can we understand the above texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirectly, yes! In a direct sense, though, God's purpose is not to punish Israel but rather to show mercy to all people, the Gentiles and His own people.

The object of Romans 11 is for Paul to demonstrate two main arguments:

1. God has not rejected His people (Romans 11:1)
2. the Gentile believers must not consider that God's grace has come to them as though they were superior to the branches of the olive tree to which they have
   been grafted in (Romans 11:17-20)

So, though the transgression of God's people has worked for the benefit of the Gentiles (as God's grace was extended to the Gentiles, as a consequence of His people's disobedience), so too the grafting in of the Gentiles will work for the benefit of the whole of Israel, as they see His mercy to the Gentiles even in the Gentiles' former disobedience, and are jealous to obtain salvation for themselves, so that He may show them mercy once again (Romans 11:11, 26, 32)